# how to make hard disk partition in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have bought a new laptop there are only two partition one main part and another for recovery.How can I make partition without formating?

Comment: Please read our FAQ next time, this question is more suitable for our sister site superuser.com, I'll move it over for you.

Comment: Look in Disk management, you may have 4 partitions, one may be hidden, if you have 4 you cannot make any more.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to click the `Start Orb` and then right click on `Computer`, and go to `Storage` > `Disk Management`.

Find the biggest disk and choose the `Shrink` option - if you can't reduce much, you may want to first defragment the hard drive.

[image]

Next, just create the partitions as usual.

However, unless you have a specific reason, it is a lot easier to manage a machine with just one partition! I used to create a partition for everything, but it is so hard to guess what you want in years to come and it can be a pain to maintain, backup etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Control Panel -> System and Security, you can choose `create and format hard disk partitions`.

Here you can shrink your main partition and create a new one in the freed up space.

Answer (score 0):

Complete info about managing partitions can be found here:
[How to Manage Your Disks using the Disk Management Utility](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-manage-your-disks-using-disk-management-utility)